# Sum of numbers occurring in the multiplication table of 8. What's wrong with my code? Desirable output is 440, and I'm getting 32303304

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int num,i,sum=0;
  printf("Enter the number:");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
  {
    num = num*i;
    sum += num;
  }
  printf("%d",sum);
  return 0;
}
```

this is the code i have written and i don't know why this is not working?

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger (and/or add debug print statements), step thru it line by line, examine the control flow and variable values. Have you done that? If so, where do you find things first start behaving in a way you don't expect?

Comment: You don't need `num = num * i;`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I Think doing nun *= i; was the problem.
I tried again by creating the another variable as a "result" and i store the multiple of num  (result = num * i ) in result and then sum+= result;

Answer (score 1):

you should not change the num which is 8 in your case.
do it like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int num,i,sum=0;
printf("Enter the number:");
scanf("%d",&num);
for(i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
 sum += num*i;
}
printf("%d",sum);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Elaboration will greatly improve this answer. What is the error? Why will this fix the error?

Comment: Code only answers that don't describe why they fix the issue aren't terribly useful.

Answer (score 0):

You’re changing `num` each time through the loop, so you’re not actually adding the multiples of the input you think you are. Add some logging or run it in a debugger for good visibility into the problem.